# Can't scroll after searching when dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation is true

Tags: swift, uisearchbar, nstableview, uisearchcontroller

I want to not be able to scroll when I click on the search bar. After searching something (typing and pressing the search button), I want to be able to scroll through the results.

I am using `dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = true` to not be able to scroll while the search bar is selected.

The problem is that I can't scroll through the results because of `dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation`.

**Video:** https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gfyOpfiM1yg

How can I achieve the desired behaviour?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A workaround I found is:

```
func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    self.tableView.isScrollEnabled = false
}

func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    self.tableView.isScrollEnabled = true
}
```

but there isn't any dim anymore to notice the user that he can't scroll...